# how to stop kafka python consumer after getting a record I want to , and do my rest of the processes

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to consume all the messages from beginning each time I run the consumer in python and stop if I get a desired record and end the consumer then continue with rest of my processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [seek](https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.2/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.seek) each time you start your consumer(use OFFSET_BEGINNING). This will set consume position for partition to offset. After this, keep processing messages as usual.

When you encounter the record after which you need to stop Consumer, use [close](https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.2/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.close)

Comment: @user2407164 Please consider [accepting the answer if it helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)